# Spring Security no JWT token on video streaming

Tags: spring, security, jwt, mp4

i am using Spring Security, JWT & S3 to stream my mp4 file.

Here i created a small test video player in order to show you my problem. Notice! This works  fine without security. But as soon as i use a secured endpoint it fails.

The problem seems to be that the jwt token is only send on the very first fetch of the first chunk. When the second chunk gets fetched, there is no jwt token in the request. Can someone help me out to resolve the problem?

```
javascript video player

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Video Streaming with JWT</title>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="videoPlayer" width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
        <!-- Placeholder source, will be updated dynamically -->
        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script>
        const jwtToken = 'JWT'
        const fetchOptions = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`
            }
        };

        // Fetch the video URL with the JWT header
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/videos/files/6634ddaf-90dc-4f1c-8f10-e4c9b9927eaa', fetchOptions)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.url; // Get the URL from the response
            })
            .then(videoURL => {
                // Set the fetched URL as the source for the video element
                const video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
                const source = video.querySelector('source');
                source.src = videoURL;
                video.load(); // Load the updated source
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('There was a problem fetching the video:', error);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
Websecurity

package de.initium.cartop.security;

import de.initium.cartop.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import de.initium.cartop.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import de.initium.cartop.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
//@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity()
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                                               auth
                                                       .requestMatchers("/v1/auth/**",
                                                                        "/v1/email/**",
                                                                        "v1/forgot-password/**",
                                                                        "/actuator/**",
                                                                        "/v1/auftrag/create")
                                                       .permitAll()
                                                       .anyRequest()
                                                       .authenticated()
                );

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(),
                             UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```
Authtokenfilter to get & verify the jwt token + claims

@Slf4j
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                                                                                                             null,
                                                                                                             userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder
                        .getContext()
                        .setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("error JWT validation: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request,
                             response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7,
                                        headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

```
RestController Get Method

    @GetMapping("/files/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getVideoFile(@PathVariable UUID id, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        videoService.getVideoFile(id,
                                  response);

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .build();
    }
```

```
Sending the chunks directly to the outputstream

    @Override
    public void getVideoFile(UUID id, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        Video video = mapper.convert(videoRepository
                                             .findById(id)
                                             .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new));

        ResponseInputStream responseInputStream = s3Service.getFile(video.getVideoPfad());

        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,
                           "video/mp4");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead;
        try {
            while ((bytesRead = responseInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                response
                        .getOutputStream()
                        .write(buffer,
                               0,
                               bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        // Close the response output stream and the S3 response stream
        responseInputStream.close();
    }
```